# From speed vector to motor control

Tags: control, motor, movement

I'm working with Mona robot (image bellow).
The movement is controlled by settings the speed of each wheel.
I'm trying to find a way to convert a speed vector into motor control so that the robot will follow this vector.
The basic solution would be to orient to robot in the direction of the vector the to move forward. But I'm looking for something smoother.

I have no idea how to process this.

[image: Mona robot]